# tkinter asksaveasfile function opens folders

Tags: python, tkinter

When I use tkinter's `asksaveasfile` function, it inadvertenly opens up folders instead of saving a file which just so happens to be named that folder.

Given the example code:

```
import tkinter.tkFileDialog

f = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
```

And a file structure, such as:

```
Desktop (initial directory)
 | ----------> example (folder)
```

where Desktop is the initial directory and example is a folder in that directory

If you where to attempt to enter the text "example", then instead of creating that file, the folder named example opens instead.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The default and expected behavior of a filedialog is to be able to paste a path to access a specific folder, so this will conflict what you want to achieve here.

One option could be to provide the extension in the default file name :

```
f = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', 
                               initialfile='.txt', # or even a default name
                               defaultextension='.txt')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, adding '.txt' did not seem to work (as it did not even show .txt in the file name entry section)

Comment: did you use the same syntax ? i can make it work for python2 or 3 with `filedialog`.. maybe a platform specific behavior ?

Comment: I know that this works fine on macOS, but on Windows it doesn't seem to